# Problems compiling after upgrading to OS X 10.8 and Xcode 4.4

Tags: xcode

I opened one of my existing projects after upgrading and can no longer compile. Below is a screenshot of the type of warnings I get. What is this related to?

[image: Screenshot of warning messages]

Comment: Can you show the code where the error is?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can point to any particular code. All the warnings seem to be related to system or Framework files that I haven't touched.

Comment: Try to disable ARC (in you project's build settings enter ARC and change YES to NO at `Automatic Reference Counting`. Then let us know what happens

Comment: But my project was already dependent on ARC, would that break it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to compile. As I suspected, the problem was buried in one of the "Build Settings", which I'm not too proficient in. Thankfully I had another project to compare with.

For some reason my "Framework Search Paths" were populated with some system paths. Once I cleared those, everything compiled!